# Create Nodes for multiple languages in webform?

Tags: 6, webforms, i18n-l10n

I have a default Node for English, which will be translated when user logs in based on the user locale. Beside I need to create a separate node for ja(Japanese) like (`mydomain.com/node/7`).

I created a node(`nid=7`) by changing the 'Language neutral' to 'Japanese' language. when I hit the node it not gets translated to Japanese.

Is there any way to get it translated?

Comment: which version of durpal you are using?

Comment: do you using webform module?

Comment: yes am using webform module

Comment: any idea on this issues?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have installed drupal 6 and cant test. my first idea was about your mistake configuration.:(

Comment: is there any specific way to change the code when particular node is hit? does that solve the problem? if means please give me some idea.

Comment: yes,drupal has very usful api to do this, as a expamle `node_view`

Comment: does drupal6.x supports webform localization module?

Comment: Reall I dont remember,I migrate to 7 about 1.5 year ago completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your problem is because mistake configuration of translation

Enable translation support for a content type

- Navigate to the Content types administration page (Administration >
  Content > Types in Drupal 6, or Administration > Structure > Content
  types in Drupal 7).
- Select a content type you want translated, and select "edit", then "Workflow settings" for Drupal 6 or "Publishing options" for
  Drupal 7.
- At the "Multilingual support" section, select "Enabled, with translation".
     Be sure to save each content type after enabling multilingual support.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using drupal 6. As per you suggestion i saw in admin area. it shows default webform which is enabled with multilingual support.so any other area should i change? pls help